# How to add table to database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to use this code to add a table to a database in a Flask app on localhost - but it does not work. What should I do?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql://postgres:123@localhost:5432/postgres'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()
```

Comment: What do happen? Is there an exception you are facing? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my app name from "flask-hello-app" to "app"
and typed these 3 commands in terminal:

```
python
from app import db
db.create_all()
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

db.session.commit()

Good luck.

Comment: still nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I just try your code using both Postgres and MySQL

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://root:55665566@localhost:5432/test'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

# from yourapplication import db
db.create_all()
```

Since I have created the table successfully,
I suggest you check some details below

1. Check the role attribute for the account.
   [image]
2. Check the connection to the database, using command \du to confirm your accounts info, suppose you need to create a user 'postgres' which should show up in the table above.